# Is there any academic research going on regarding Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, research

Is there any academic research going on regarding Stack Exchange?

I would be interested in helping, if someone is writing a paper.

Comment: There was definitely somebody writing a paper at some point, I remember them talking about it, but I don't know exactly what it was about

Comment: I would love to have government money and academic recognition because I wanted it too.

Comment: There was actually a research paper or summat written about Stack Overflow that was posted here on Meta. I'll see if i can retrieve it. I remember that it partly discussed some aspects of motivation.

Comment: Thank you.  I would love to get involved writing a paper on SE.

Comment: Okay, I realize I'm late to the commenting party, but perhaps you were thinking of [this answer by Aarobot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56810/131713), @GraceNote?

Comment: @PopularDemand This question seems to be is about papers that are *currently being written*, but that one is about papers that are already finished.

Comment: Hm, perhaps. All the "academic papers" questions seemed to be moving in the same direction, so I wanted to link them all together. The first half of this question could be interpreted either way. The second part suggests that you're right, but it's also the part that didn't age well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Lena Mamykina (Human-Centered Computing at Columbia University) and Björn Hartmann (UC Berkeley) are conducting a study.

Papers have also been published:

- Evolution of Two Sided Markets. Ravi Kumar, Yury Lifshits (Yahoo! Research), and Andrew Tomkins (Google). [PDF](http://www.wsdm-conference.org/2010/proceedings/docs/p311.pdf).
- Causal Discovery in Social Media Using Quasi-Experimental Designs. Hüseyin Oktay, Brian J. Taylor, David D. Jensen (Knowledge Discovery Laboratory, Department of Computer Science, University of Massachusetts Amherst). [PDF](http://www.cs.umass.edu/%7Ehoktay/pub/soma2010.pdf).

Source: Stack Overflow blog post [Academic Papers Using Stack Overflow Data](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data/).

Answer (score 1):

I just did a literature research and collected actual research publications in [a Mendeley bibliography on Stack Exchange](http://www.mendeley.com/groups/2395351/stackexchange/). Feel free to contribute! We may also collect papers at this question.

Comment: Before publishing, please get the name right? (The Stack Exchange network sites often have a space in their name!)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll add a space character!

Comment: Except that now the Mendeley name is StackE xchange `:(`

Comment: And it's a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data (which I only discovered just now)