# Is there any published research on Stack Overflow in the last 18 months?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, research

A bit over a year ago, there was [a blog post about published research involving Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data/).

This was also referenced in [Is there any academic research going on regarding Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71947/is-there-any-academic-research-going-on-regarding-stack-exchange)

Are there any more recent publications involving Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange?  Also, what is the best way to keep informed of such work? By keeping in contact with the Stack Exchange folks directly?

Comment: Hmm, I noticed that one of the papers studies Yahoo Answers as well. Is "suck" a technical term?

Comment: Such language, how immoderate! :)  Then again, maybe YA's problem is they don't have the wonderful moderators that I've come to know and love on SO.

Comment: Here is the list of such papers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three results from 2011 I got from quick ACM Digital Library and IEEE Xplore searches:

- [How do programmers ask and answer questions on the web?: NIER track](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6032523)
- [Getting the Most out of the Web](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5672525)
- [Design lessons from the fastest Q&A site in the west](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1978942.1979366&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=64715861&CFTOKEN=20653467) ← **best title award**

Note - All linked articles above cost $ and require user account.

Full citations:

<sup>Treude, C., Barzilay, O., & Storey, M. (2011). How do programmers ask and answer questions on the web?: NIER track. *Software Engineering (ICSE), 2011 33rd International Conference on*, 2011(21-28 May 2011), 804-807.</sup>

<sup>Osbourn, T. (2011). Getting the Most out of the Web. *Software, IEEE*, 28(1), 96.</sup>

<sup>Mamykina, L., Manoim, B., Mittal, M., Hripcsak, G., & Hartmann, B. (2011). Design lessons from the fastest q&a site in the west. Proceedings of the 2011 annual conference on Human factors in computing systems , 2011, 2857-2866.</sup>

Comment: "How Do Programmers Ask and Answer Questions on the Web?" is available via [the first author's website](http://ctreude.wordpress.com/publications/) (click the "acm" link for the paper, listed under "Refereed Short Conference Papers").

Answer (score 1):

To follow up, there seem to be a few papers that mention SO on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%2Bstackoverflow.com+questions+answers).  As "Stack Overflow" (with and without the space) is a very common term, I added [questions answers] to the query.  In many cases, the papers only mention SO as an example, rather than as a subject of study.

Moreover, some of the results are *on* SO or another StackExchange site.