# Academic papers using Stack Exchange data

Tags: discussion, research, academic

As a result of [being interested in Stack Overflow data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132087/repository-of-so-based-academic-papers) myself, the need arose to track other Stack Overflow-based research.

The following is an attempt to list the academic papers mentioning Stack Overflow/Exchange or using Stack Exchange data. This also includes the works mentioned in [the SO blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data/) that started the trend, as well as two other questions on meta, [one from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71947/is-there-any-academic-research-going-on-regarding-stack-exchange), and [another one from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105168/is-there-any-published-research-on-stack-overflow-in-the-last-18-months).

If you know of papers that are not listed, please edit the answer directly.

I realised it might be useful to have all the BibTeX entries in a single file, so I started [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059).

Comment: Year 2123: Stack Overflow is in the Top-20 of the "ISI Master Journal List" due to the number of citations and accumulated impact factor..

Comment: The answers are split because SO allows at most 30k characters per answer.

Comment: what about one answer per year?

Comment: Does [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06487) fulfill what are you asking for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### 2023

- Saikat Mondal, Debajyoti Mondal, Chanchal K. Roy. **Investigating Technology Usage Span by Analyzing Users' Q&A Traces in Stack Overflow**. 30th Asia-Pacific Software Engineering Conference (APSEC 2023) [[Preprint]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.03182)
- Saikat Mondal, Mohammad Masudur Rahman, Chanchal K. Roy. **Do Subjectivity and Objectivity Always Agree? A Case Study with Stack Overflow Questions**. International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2023) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.03563)
- Krishna, V., Antulov-Fantulin, N. **Temporal-Weighted Bipartite Graph Model for Sparse Expert Recommendation in Community Question Answering.**, In Proceedings of the 31st ACM Conference on User Modeling, Adaptation and Personalization, pp. 156-163. 2023. (UMAP '23)  [[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1145/3565472.3592957)]

#### 2022

- Saikat Mondal, Gias Uddin, Chanchal K. Roy. **Automatic Prediction of Rejected Edits in Stack Overflow**. Empirical Software Engineering (EMSE) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.03281)
- Krishna, V., Vasiliauskaite, V. & Antulov-Fantulin, N. **Question routing via activity-weighted modularity-enhanced factorization**, Social Network Analysis and Mining.  [[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13278-022-00978-6)]
- Agnieszka Geras, Grzegorz Siudem, Marek Gagolewski. **Time to vote: Temporal clustering of user activity on Stack Overflow**, Journal of the Association for Information Science and Technology  (JASIST), 73(12), 2022, 1681–1691.  [[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1002/asi.24658)]
- Hengyi Fu, Sanghee Oh. **Online community development in the early stages: the life cycle model application to Medical Sciences Stack Exchange.** Aslib Journal of Information Management. [[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1108/AJIM-11-2021-0345)]
- W. Ledbetter and J. Springer, **Answer Comments As Reviews: Predicting Acceptance By Measuring Valence On Stack Exchange**, 2022 IEEE International Conference on Big Data (Big Data), Osaka, Japan, 2022, pp. 4782-4791, [[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1109/BigData55660.2022.10021109)]

#### 2021

- Mohamad Yazdaninia, David Lo, Ashkan Sami. **Characterization and Prediction of Questions without Accepted Answers on Stack Overflow**, Proceedings of the 29th IEEE/ACM International Conference on Program Comprehension (*ICPC 2021*) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.11386.pdf)
- Saikat Mondal, Mohammad Masudur Rahman, Chanchal K. Roy, Kevin Schneider. **The Reproducibility of Programming-Related Issues in Stack Overflow Questions**. Empirical Software Engineering (EMSE) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12204)
- Saikat Mondal, Banani Roy. **Reproducibility Challenges and Their Impacts on Technical Q&A Websites: The Practitioners' Perspectives**. Innovations in Software Engineering Conference (ISEC 2022) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.10056)
- Rodrigo F. Silva, Mohammad M. Rahman, Carlos E. C. Dantas Chanchal Roy, Foutse Khomh, Marcelo A. Maia. **Improved retrieval of programming solutions with code examples using a multi-featured score**. Journal of Systems and Software. Vol. 181. [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jss.2021.111063) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02702)
- Jiakun Liu, Sebastian Baltes, Christoph Treude, David Lo, Yun Zhang, Xin Xia. **Characterizing Search Activities on Stack Overflow**. Proceedings of the 29th ACM Joint European Software Engineering Conference and Symposium on the Foundations of Software Engineering (ESEC/FSE 2021). [[PDF]](https://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/fse21-search.pdf)
- Moutidis I, Williams HTP (2021).
  **Community evolution on Stack Overflow.**
  PLoS ONE 16(6): e0253010.
  [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0253010)
  [[BibTex]](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/citation/bibtex?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0253010)
  [[PDF]](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0253010&type=printable)
- Saikat Mondal, Gias Uddin and Chanchal K. Roy. **Rollback Edit Inconsistencies in Developer Forum**. The 18th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2021) [[PDF]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350241097_Rollback_Edit_Inconsistencies_in_Developer_Forum)
- Kaibo Cao, Chunyang Chen, Sebastian Baltes, Christoph Treude, Xiang Chen. **Automated Query Reformulation for Efficient Search based on Query Logs From Stack Overflow**. Proceedings of the 43rd IEEE/ACM International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2021). [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.00826.pdf)
- Haoxiang Zhang, Shaowei Wang, Heng Li, Tse-Hsun (Peter) Chen, and Ahmed E. Hassan, **A Study of C/C++ Code Weaknesses on Stack Overflow**. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE), 2021. [[PDF]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349144767_A_Study_of_CC_Code_Weaknesses_on_Stack_Overflow)
- Haoxiang Zhang, Shaowei Wang, Tse-Hsun (Peter) Chen, and Ahmed E. Hassan, **Are Comments on Stack Overflow Well Organized for Easy Retrieval by Developers?**. ACM Transactions on Software Engineering and Methodology (TOSEM), 2021. [[PDF]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3434279)
- Saikat Mondal, C M Khaled Saifullah, Avijit Bhattacharjee, Masud Rahman and Chanchal K. Roy. **Early Detection and Guidelines to Improve Unanswered Questions on Stack Overflow**. Innovations in Software Engineering Conference (ISEC 2021) [[PDF]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348819989_Early_Detection_and_Guidelines_to_Improve_Unanswered_Questions_on_Stack_Overflow)

#### 2020

- Rodrigo Silva, Chanchal Roy, Masud Rahman, Kevin Schneider, Klerisson Paixao, Carlos Dantas, Marcelo Maia. **CROKAGE: Effective Solution Recommendations for Programming Tasks by Leveraging Crowd Knowledge**, Empirical Software Engineering, 25, 4707–4758. [[PDF]](https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s10664-020-09863-2?sharing_token=awi5EkMEXP-2O-O6BG0CB_e4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY7vnnGFx2oleCeEhxe_sXNvomG1VzarYXSIBc9U7Mskt3n1DO1WF_NhbMzO7R9mC_2Vzv6KU-b3dSGFEX2a-BEUCJ1L8Q6QcvYKSS_dcquLmLVOMvEw9ojujzIlqJSLskE%3D)
  [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10664-020-09863-2)
- Preetha Chatterjee, Minji Kong, Lori Pollock. **Finding help with programming errors: An exploratory study of novice software engineers’ focus in stack overflow posts**,
  Journal of Systems and Software, Volume 159, 2020.
  [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jss.2019.110454)
- Saikat Mondal, Gias Uddin, and Chanchal K. Roy. **Automatic Identification of Rollback Edit with Reasons in Stack Overflow Q&A Site**. 36th International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution (ICSME-RR) 2020. [[PDF]](https://osf.io/sjgnz/)
- Timur Bachschi, Aniko Hannak, Florian Lemmerich, and Johannes Wachs. **From Asking to Answering: Getting More Involved on Stack Overflow**. arXiv preprint: 2010.04025, 2020. [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.04025.pdf)
- Sebastian Baltes, Christoph Treude, and Martin Robillard. **Contextual Documentation Referencing on Stack Overflow**. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE). [[PDF]](http://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/tse19-condor.pdf)
- Sebastian Baltes and Christoph Treude. **Code Duplication on Stack Overflow.** Proceedings of the 42nd International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE-NIER 2020). [[PDF]](http://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/icse20-clones.pdf)
- Sebastian Baltes and Markus Wagner. **An Annotated Dataset of Stack Overflow Post Edits.** Genetic and Evolutionary Computation Conference Companion Proceedings (GECCO 2020 Companion) - 9th Genetic Improvement Workshop. [[PDF]](http://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/geccogi20-soedits.pdf)
- Zhou, J., Wang, S., Bezemer, C. P., & Hassan, A. E. **Bounties on technical Q&A sites: a case study of Stack Overflow bounties.** *Empirical Software Engineering*, 25(1), 139-177. [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10664-019-09744-3)
- Sengupta, S., & Haythornthwaite, C. **Learning with comments: An analysis of comments and community on Stack Overflow**. In Proceedings of the 53rd Hawaii International Conference on System Sciences. [[PDF]](https://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/10125/64096/0285.pdf)
- Blanco, Guillermo, et al. **Understanding the social evolution of the Java community in Stack Overflow: A 10-year study of developer interactions.** *Future Generation Computer Systems* 105 (2020): 446-454. [[PDF]](https://repositorium.sdum.uminho.pt/bitstream/1822/63736/1/document_52348_1.pdf)

#### 2019

- Haoxiang Zhang, Shaowei Wang, Tse-Hsun (Peter) Chen, and Ahmed E. Hassan, **Reading Answers on Stack Overflow: Not Enough!**. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE), 2019. [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8906075)
- Preetha Chatterjee, Kostadin Damevski, Lori Pollock, Vinay Augustine, and Nicholas A. Kraft. **Exploratory Study of Slack Q&A Chats as a Mining Source for Software Engineering Tools**, The 16th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR). [PDF](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.udel.edu/dist/8/2570/files/2019/03/PID5819473-1jstqpt.pdf)
- László Tóth, Balázs Nagy, Dávid Janthó, László Vidács, Tibor Gyimóthy. **Towards an Accurate Prediction of the Question Quality at Stack Overflow Using a Deep-Learning-Based NLP Approach**. 14th International Conference on Software Technologies (ICSOFT) [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.5220/0007971306310639)
- Suyu Ma, Zhenchang Xing, Chunyang Chen, Cheng Chen, Lizhen Qu, Guoqiang Li. **Easy-to-Deploy API Extraction by Multi-Level Feature Embedding and Transfer Learning**. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE) [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/API_NER_TSE2019.pdf)
- Xiang Chen, Chunyang Chen, Dun Zhang, Zhenchang Xing. **SEthesaurus: WordNet in Software Engineering**. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE) [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/SEthesaurusWordnet_TSE19.pdf) [[Tool]](https://pypi.org/project/DomainThesaurus/)
- Md Ahasanuzzaman, Muhammad Asaduzzaman, Chanchal K. Roy, Kevin A. Schneider.
  **CAPS: a supervised technique for classifying Stack Overflow posts concerning API issues.** Empirical Software Engineering **(ESE)**, 2019. [[PDF]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10664-019-09743-4)
- S. Mondal, M.M. Rahman, C.K. Roy **Can Issues Reported at Stack Overflow Questions be Reproduced? An Exploratory Study** Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (**MSR 2019**). [[PDF]](http://homepage.usask.ca/%7Emasud.rahman/papers/saikat-MSR2019-pp.pdf)
- L. Souza, E. Campos, F. Madeiral, K. Paixão, A. Rocha, M.A. Maia **Bootstrapping Cookbooks for APIs from Crowd Knowledge on Stack Overflow** Information and Software Technology, v. 111, 2019. [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.09174)
- R. Silva, C.K. Roy, M. Rahman, K. Schneider, K. Paixão, M.A. Maia **Recommending Comprehensive Solutions for Programming Tasks by Mining Crowd Knowledge**. Proc. of the International Conference on Program Comprehension (ICPC), 2019. [[PDF]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2019/ICPC2019.pdf)
- Haoxiang Zhang, Shaowei Wang, Tse-Hsun (Peter) Chen, Ying Zou, Ahmed E. Hassan, **An Empirical Study of Obsolete Answers on Stack Overflow**. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE), 2019. [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8669958)
- Anna May, Johannes Wachs, Aniko Hannak. **Gender differences in participation and reward on Stack Overflow.** Empirical Software Engineering, 2019. [[PDF]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10664-019-09685-x.pdf)
- Agnieszka Geras, Grzegorz Siudem, Marek Gagolewski. **Should we introduce a dislike button for academic articles?**, Journal of the Association for Information Science and Technology (JASIST) 71(2), 2020, 221–229. [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1002/asi.24231)
- Emillie Thiselton, Christoph Treude. **Enhancing Python Compiler Error Messages via Stack Overflow.** arXiv preprint arXiv:1906.11456v1, 2019. [[PDF]](https://cs.adelaide.edu.au/%7Echristoph/esem19.pdf)
- Sebastian Baltes, Christoph Treude, and Stephan Diehl. **SOTorrent:  Studying the Origin, Evolution, and Usage of Stack Overflow Code Snippets**. Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2019). [[PDF]](https://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/msr19-sotorrent.pdf) [[website]](http://sotorrent.org)

#### 2018

- Sk Adnan Hassan, Dipto Das, Anindya Iqbal, Amiangshu Bosu, Rifat Shahriyar and Toufique Ahmed.  **SOQDE: A Supervised Learning based Question Difficulty Estimation Model for Stack Overflow**. 25th Asia-Pacific Software Engineering Conference (APSEC), 445-454, 2018. [[DOI]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8719532)
- M. Ahasanuzzaman, M. Asaduzzaman, C. K. Roy, and K. A. Schneider.  **Classifying Stack Overflow Posts On API Issues**. IEEE 25th International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER), 2018. [PDF](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8330213)
- Rodrigo F. G. Silva, Klerisson Paixao, Marcelo de A. Maia. **Duplicate Question Detection in Stack Overflow: A Reproducibility Study**. IEEE 25th International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER), 2018. [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1109/SANER.2018.8330262) [PDF](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8330262) [Preprint](https://peerj.com/preprints/26555/)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing, Yang Liu. **What's Spain's Paris? Mining Analogical Libraries from Q&A Discussions**. Springer Empirical Software Engineering [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/analogyJournal_EMSE.pdf)
- Chunyang Chen, Xi Chen, Jiamou Sun, Zhenchang Xing and Guoqiang Li. **Data-Driven Proactive Policy Assurance of Post Quality in Community Q&A Sites**. Proc. ACM Hum.-Comput. Interact. 2, CSCW, Article 33 [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/proactiveEdit_cscw18.pdf)
- Zakaria Mehrab, Raquib Bin Yousuf, Ibrahim Asadullah Tahmid, Rifat Shahriyar. **Mining Developer Questions about Major Web Frameworks**. Proceedings of the 14th International Conference on Web Information Systems and Technologies - Volume 1: WEBIST, 191-198, 2018. [[dblp]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/html/conf/webist/MehrabYTS18) [[PDF]](http://www.insticc.org/Primoris/Resources/PaperPdf.ashx?idPaper=69295) [[DOI]](http://www.scitepress.org/DigitalLibrary/Link.aspx?doi=10.5220%2F0006929501910198)
- Shaowei Wang, Tse-Hsun Chen, Ahmed, E. Hassan, **How Do Users Revise Answers on Technical Q&A Websites? A Case Study on Stack Overflow.** IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE), 2018. [[PDF]](https://sail.cs.queensu.ca/Downloads/TSE2018_HowDoUsersReviseAnswersOnTechnicalQ&AWebsitesACaseStudyOnStackOverflow.pdf)
- Sebastian Baltes and Stephan Diehl. **Usage and Attribution of Stack Overflow Code Snippets in GitHub Projects**. Empirical Software Engineering, 2018. [[DOI]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10664-018-9650-5) [[PDF]](http://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/emse18-snippets.pdf)
- Yi Huang, Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing, Tian Lin and Yang Liu. **Tell Them Apart: Distilling Technology Differences from Crowd-Scale Comparison Discussions**. The 33rd IEEE/ACM International Conference on Automated Software Engineering (ASE) [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/diffSimilarTech.pdf) [[Tool]](https://difftech.herokuapp.com/)
- Yuhao Wu, Shaowei Wang,Cor-Paul Bezemer, Katsuro Inoue. **How Do Developers Utilize Source Code from Stack Overflow?** Empirical Software Engineering, 2018. [[PDF]](http://sail.cs.queensu.ca/Downloads/EMSE2018_HowDoDevelopersUtilizeSourceCodeFromStackOverflow.pdf)
- Fabio Calefato, Filippo Lanubile, Nicole Novielli. **How to Ask for Technical Help? Evidence-based Guidelines for Writing Questions on Stack Overflow**. Information and Software Technology, Volume 94, February 2018, Pages 186-207 [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04692.pdf)
- Denae Ford, Kristina Lustig, Jeremy Banks, Chris Parnin.
  **“We Don’t Do That Here”: How Collaborative Editing with Mentors Improves Engagement in Social Q&A Communities**.
  Proceedings of the 2018 CHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems (CHI '18), Paper No. 608, April 2018.
  [[PDF]](http://chrisparnin.me/pdf/chi18.pdf)
- Jing Li, Aixin Sun, and Zhenchang Xing. **Learning to Answer Programming Questions with Software Documentation through Social Context Embedding**.
  Information Sciences (INS). Volumes 448–449, Pages 36-52, June 2018, Elsevier. [[PDF]](https://authors.elsevier.com/a/1Wj-54ZQDs6Wb)
- Jing Li, Zhenchang Xing and Ashad Kabir.
  **Leveraging Official Content and Social Context to Recommend Software Documentation**. IEEE Transactions on Services Computing (TSC). IEEE, 2018. [[PDF]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8307192/)
- Sebastian Baltes, Lorik Dumani, Christoph Treude, and Stephan Diehl. **SOTorrent: Reconstructing and Analyzing the Evolution of Stack Overflow Posts**. Proceedings of the 15th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2018). [[PDF]](http://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/msr18-sotorrent.pdf) [[website]](https://empirical-software.engineering/assets/pdf/msr19-sotorrent.pdf)
- Jin Liu, Pingyi Zhou, Zijiang Yang, Xiao Liu and John Grundy.
  **FastTagRec: fast tag recommendation for software information sites.**
  Automated Software Engineering 2018, pages 1-27.
  [[PDF]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10515-018-0239-4)
- Taniya Saini, Sachin Tripathi.
  **Predicting tags for stack overflow questions using different classifiers.**
  4th International Conference on Recent Advances in Information Technology (RAIT 2018).
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8389059)

Comment: Hi! I've made this a community wiki post like the others: The one you took this part from shows that there's a lot of people with less than 100 reputation points in the revision history, and this way they can contribute to this new answer with edits too.

Comment: "László Tóth"? Surely not the same László Tóth who took a sledgehammer to that one Michaelangelo statue?

Comment: me reading an abstract that shows that the researchers don't understand something about how we do things or why we do things the way we do: hrnnggggggg

Comment: [A candidate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425317/request-for-feedback-on-research-study-related-to-vulnerable-iot-related-code-sn).

Answer (score 144):

#### 2017

- Shaowei Wang, Tse-Hsun Chen, Ahmed E. Hassan. **Understanding the Factors for Fast Answers in Technical Q&A Websites: An Empirical Study on Four Stack Exchange  Websites**. Empirical Software Engineering (2017). [[PDF]](http://sail.cs.queensu.ca/Downloads/EMSE2017_UnderstandingTheFactorsForFastAnswersInQ&AWebsites.pdf)
- Shaowei Wang, David Lo, Bogdan Vasilescu, Alexander Serebrenik. **EnTagRec++: An Enhanced Tag Recommendation System for Software Information Sites**. Empirical Software Engineering (2017). [[PDF]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aserebre/EMSE-EnTagRecPlusPlus.pdf)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing, and Yang Liu. **By the Community & For the Community: A Deep Learning Approach to Assist Collaborative Editing in Q&A Sites**. Proc. ACM Hum.-Comput. Interact. 1, CSCW, Article 32 (December 2017) [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/correctSentence.pdf)
- Fabio Calefato, Filippo Lanubile, Federico Maiorano, Nicole Novielli. **Sentiment Polarity Detection for Software Development**. Empirical Software Engineering, https://doi.org/10.1007/s10664-017-9546-9. [PDF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.02984)
- Reza Gharibi, Mohammad Malekzadeh. **Gamified Incentives: A Badge Recommendation Model to Improve User Engagement in Social Networking Websites** International Journal of Advanced Computer Science and Applications(IJACSA), 8(5), 2017 [[PDF]](http://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume8No5/Paper_33-Gamified_Incentives_A_Badge_Recommendation.pdf) [[[Code]]](https://github.com/h4iku/stack-badges)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing, Ximing Wang. **Unsupervised Software-Specific Morphological Forms Inference from Informal Discussions** The 39th International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE), pp. 450-461 [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/seThesaurus.pdf) [[website]](http://se-thesaurus.appspot.com)
- Azad, Shams, Peter C. Rigby, and Latifa Guerrouj. **Generating API Call Rules from Version History and Stack Overflow Posts.** ACM Transactions on Software Engineering and Methodology (TOSEM) 25.4 (2017): 29. [[PDF]](https://users.encs.concordia.ca/~pcr/paper/Azad2017TOSEM.pdf)
- Abdalkareem, Rabe, Emad Shihab, and Juergen Rilling. **On Code Reuse from StackOverflow: An Exploratory Study on Android Apps.** Information and Software Technology (2017).[[website]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950584917303610)
- Abdalkareem, Rabe, Emad Shihab, and Juergen Rilling. **What Do Developers Use the Crowd For? A Study Using Stack Overflow.** IEEE Software 34.2 (2017): 53-60.[[PDF]](http://das.encs.concordia.ca/uploads/2016/12/Abdalkareem_SW2017.pdf)
- Campbell, Brock Angus, and Christoph Treude. **NLP2Code: Code Snippet Content Assist via Natural Language Tasks.** arXiv preprint arXiv:1701.05648 (2017).[[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05648)
- Convertino, Gregorio, et al. **Toward a mixed-initiative QA system: from studying predictors in Stack Exchange to building a mixed-initiative tool.** International Journal of Human-Computer Studies 99 (2017): 1-20. [[website]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071581916301501)
- Vinayakarao, Venkatesh, et al. **Anne: Improving source code search using entity retrieval approach.** Proceedings of the Tenth ACM International Conference on Web Search and Data Mining. ACM, 2017. [[website]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3018691)
- Alexey Zagalsky, Daniel M. German, Margaret-Anne Storey, Carlos Gómez Teshima, and Germán Poo-Caamaño. 2017. 
  **How the R Community Creates and Curates Knowledge: An Extended Study of Stack Overflow and Mailing Lists**. 
  *Journal of Empirical Software Engineering (EMSE)*, August 2017,
  Springer US.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10664-017-9536-y)
  [[PDF]](http://alexeyza.com/pdf/emse-msr2017.pdf)
  [[DATA]](https://zenodo.org/record/831805)
- Yuji Mizobuchi, Kuniharu Takayama. **Two improvements to detect duplicates in Stack Overflow.** 24th IEEE International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER 2017). [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7884678)
- Pingyi Zhou, Jin Liu, Zijiang Yang, Guangyou Zhou.
  **Scalable tag recommendation for software information sites.**
  24th IEEE International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER 2017).
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7884628)

#### 2016

- M. Ahasanuzzaman, M. Asaduzzaman, Chanchal K. Roy, Kevin A. Schneider: **Mining duplicate questions in stack overflow ?**. 13th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2016). [[PDF]](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2901770)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing **SimilarTech: Automatically Recommend Analogical Libraries across Different Programming Languages**. The 31st IEEE/ACM International Conference on Automated Software Engineering (ASE) [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/analogyTool.pdf)
- Guibin Chen, Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing, and Bowen Xu. **Learning a Dual-Language Vector Space for Domain-Specific Cross-Lingual Question Retrieval**. The 31st IEEE/ACM International Conference on Automated Software Engineering (ASE) [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/ASE2016_gbchen.pdf)
- Jing Li, Zhenchang Xing, Deheng Ye and Xuejiao Zhao. **From Discussion to Wisdom: Web Resource Recommendation  for Hyperlinks in Stack Overflow**. Proceedings of the 31st ACM Symposium on Applied Computing (SAC 2016). [[PDF]](http://www.li-jing.com/papers/WisLinker.pdf)
- Srba, Ivan. **Promoting Sustainability and Transferability of Community Question Answering.** Information Sciences and Technologies 8.2 (2016): 10. [[PDF]](http://acmbulletin.fiit.stuba.sk/abstracts/srba2016.pdf)
- Boudaer, Glenn, and Johan Loeckx. **Enriching Topic Modelling with Users' Histories for Improving Tag Prediction in Q&A Systems.** Proceedings of the 25th International Conference Companion on World Wide Web. International World Wide Web Conferences Steering Committee, 2016.[[PDF]](http://www2016.net/proceedings/companion/p669.pdf)
- Eduardo Campos, Martin Monperrus, Marcelo Maia. **Searching Stack Overflow for API-usage-related Bug Fixes Using Snippet-based Queries.** Proc. of 26th  International Conference on Computer Science and Software Engineering (CASCON), Toronto, Canada, p. 1-11, 2016. [[PDF]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2016/cascon-preprint.pdf)
- Utkarsh Upadhyay, Isabel Valera, Manuel Gomez-Rodriguez. **Uncovering the Dynamics of Crowdlearning and the Value of Knowledge**. 10th ACM International Conference on Web Search and Data Mining Conference (WSDM 2016). (Submitted on 14 Dec 2016.) [[PDF]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04831)
- Fernanda Delfim, Klérisson Paixão, Damien Cassou, Marcelo Maia. **Redocumenting APIs with crowd knowledge: a coverage analysis based on question types**. Journal of the Brazilian Computer Society (JBCS). (Volume: 29, Issue: 1, Dec. 2016) Open Access. [[website]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s13173-016-0049-0).
- Eduardo Campos, Lucas Souza, Marcelo Maia. **Searching Crowd Knowledge to Recommend Solutions for API Usage Tasks**. Journal of Software: Evolution and Process (JSEP). (Volume: 28, Issue: 10, Pages: 863--892). Wiley, 2016 [[PDF]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2016/jsep2016AcceptedVersion.pdf) [[website]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/smr.1800).
- Ivan Srba and Maria Bielikova. **Why is Stack Overflow Failing? Preserving Sustainability in Community Question Answering**. IEEE Software (Volume: 33, Issue: 4, July-Aug. 2016). [[website]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MS.2016.34)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing, Lei Han. **TechLand: Assisting Technology Landscape Inquiries with Insights from Stack Overflow**. The 32nd IEEE International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution (ICSME 2016).[[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/techLand.pdf)[[Tool]](https://github.com/tomhanlei/kg_plugin)
- Chunyang Chen, Sa Gao, Zhenchang Xing. **Mining Analogical Libraries in Q&A Discussions — Incorporating Relational and Categorical Knowledge into Word Embedding**. The 23rd IEEE International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution, and Reengineering (SANER 2016). [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/analogical_libraries.pdf) [[Tool]](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/similartech)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing. **Towards Correlating Search on Google and Asking on Stack Overflow**. The 40th IEEE Computer Society International Conference on Computers, Software & Applications (COMPSAC 2016). [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/ask_search_correlation.pdf) [[website]](http://comparetrend.appspot.com/)
- Chunyang Chen, Zhenchang Xing. **Mining Technology Landscape from Stack Overflow**. The 10th ACM/IEEE International Symposium on Empirical Software Engineering and Measurement (ESEM 2016). [[PDF]](https://chunyang-chen.github.io/publication/technology_landscape.pdf)[[Tool]](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com)
- Deheng Ye, Zhenchang Xing, Chee Yong Foo, Jing Li, and Nachiket Kapre.  **Learning to Extract API Mentions from Informal Natural Language Discussions**.  The 32nd International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution (ICSME 2016). [[PDF]](http://yedeheng.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/3/9/50390459/icsme2016.pdf)
- Deheng Ye, Zhenchang Xing, and Nachiket Kapre.  **The Structure and Dynamics of Knowledge Network in Domain-specific Q&A Sites: A Case Study of Stack Overflow**.  Journal of Empirical Software Engineering (EMSE). 2016. (IF: 2.161) [[PDF]](http://yedeheng.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/3/9/50390459/template.pdf)
- Deheng Ye, Zhenchang Xing, Chee Yong Foo, Zi Qun Ang, Jing Li, and Nachiket Kapre.  **Software-specific Named Entity Recognition in Software Engineering Social Content**.  The 23rd IEEE International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution, and Reengineering (SANER 2016). [[PDF]](http://yedeheng.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/3/9/50390459/saner2016.pdf)
- Deheng Ye, Zhenchang Xing, Jing Li, and Nachiket Kapre.  **Software-specific Part-of-speech Tagging: An Experimental Study on Stack Overflow**. The 31st ACM/SIGAPP Symposium on Applied Computing (SAC 2016). [[PDF]](http://yedeheng.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/3/9/50390459/sac2016.pdf)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Gabriele Bavota, Andrea Mocci, Massimiliano Di Penta, Rocco Oliveto, Mir Hasan, Barbara Russo, Sonia Haiduc, Michele Lanza.
  **Too Long; Didn’t Watch! Extracting Relevant Fragments from Software Development Video Tutorials**, In Proceedings of the 38th *International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2016)*.
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/profile/publications/2016a/Ponz2016a.pdf)
  [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/lucaponzanelli/too-long-didnt-watch-extracting-relevant-fragments-from-software-development-video-tutorials)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Gabriele Bavota, Andrea Mocci, Massimiliano Di Penta, Rocco Oliveto, Barbara Russo, Sonia Haiduc, Michele Lanza.
  **CodeTube: Extracting Relevant Fragments from Software Development Video Tutorials**, In Proceedings of the 38th *International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2016)*.
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/profile/publications/2016b/Ponz2016b.pdf)
- Alessandro Murgia, Daan Janssens, Serge Demeyer, Bogdan Vasilescu. 
  **Among the Machines: Human-Bot Interaction on Social Q&A Websites**, In Proceedings of the *ACM SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems (CHI 2016)*.
  [[PDF]](http://bvasiles.github.io/papers/chi16bot.pdf)
- Christoph Treude, Martin P. Robillard. **Augmenting API Documentation with Insights from Stack Overflow**, In Proceedings of the 38th *International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2016)*.
  [[PDF]](https://ctreude.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/icse16a.pdf)
- Varun Kumar, Niranjan Pedanekar. **Mining Shapes of Expertise in Online Social Q&A Communities** In Companion Proceedings of CSCW 2016, the 19th ACM Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work and Social Computing.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2818052.2869096)
  [[PDF]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Varun_Kumar36/publication/289372815_Mining_Shapes_of_Expertise_in_Online_Social_QA_Communities/links/568bddaa08ae16c414a9c4d6.pdf?inViewer=0&pdfJsDownload=0&origin=publication_detail)
- Alexey Zagalsky, Carlos Gómez Teshima, Daniel M. German, Margaret-Anne Storey, and Germán Poo-Caamaño. 2016. 
  **How the R Community Creates and Curates Knowledge: A Comparative Study of Stack Overflow and Mailing Lists**. 
  In *13th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2016)*.
  ACM, pages 441-451.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2901739.2901772)
  [[PDF]](http://alexeyza.com/pdf/msr2016.pdf)
  [[DATA]](https://github.com/thechiselgroup/R-ML-and-StackOverflow)
  [[Slides]](https://speakerdeck.com/alexeyza/msr16-how-the-r-community-creates-and-curates-knowledge)
- Ahasanuzzaman, Asaduzzaman, et al. **Mining Duplicate Questions of Stack Overflow.** IEEE/ACM 13th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2016) [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7832919)
- Lin Wang, Bin Wu, Juan Yang, Shuang Peng.
  **Personalized recommendation for new questions in community question answering.**
  IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining (ASONAM 2016).
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7752346)
- Manish Bhanu, Joydeep Chandra.
  **Exploiting response patterns for identifying topical experts in StackOverflow.**
  Eleventh International Conference on Digital Information Management (ICDIM 2016).
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7829790)

#### 2015

- Beyer, Stefanie and Pinzger, Martin **Synonym Suggestion for Tags on Stack Overflow**. Proceedings of the 2015 IEEE 23rd International Conference on Program Comprehension, ICPC '15, 2015.[[website]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2820282.2820296).
- Luis Mastrangelo, Luca Ponzanelli, Andrea Mocci, Matthias Hauswirth, Nathaniel Nystrom, Michele Lanza. **Use at Your Own Risk: The Java Unsafe API in the Wild**. In Proceedings of the International Conference on Object Oriented Programming Systems Languages & Applications (OOPSLA 2015) [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/publications/2015e/downloads/Ponz2015d.pdf)
- Sharma, Abhishek, Yuan Tian, and David Lo. **Nirmal: Automatic identification of software relevant tweets leveraging language model.** Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER), 2015 IEEE 22nd International Conference on. IEEE, 2015.[PDF](https://github.com/abhishek9sharma/abhishek9sharma.github.io/blob/master/Papers/saner15-tweets.pdf)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Gabriele Bavota, Massimiliano Di Penta, Rocco Oliveto, Michele Lanza. **Prompter: Turning the IDE into a Self-confident Programming Assistant**. Empirical Software Engineering (EMSE)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Andrea Mocci, Michele Lanza. **Summarizing Complex Development Artifacts by Mining Heterogeneous Data**. In Proceedings of the 12th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2015) [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/profile/publications/2015b/Ponz2015b.pdf)
  [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/lucaponzanelli/summarizing-complex-development-artifacts-by-mining-heterogeneous-data)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Andrea Mocci, Michele Lanza. **StORMeD: Stack Overflow Ready Made Data**. In Proceedings of the 12th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2015) [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/profile/publications/2015a/Ponz2015a.pdf)
- Nicole Novielli, Fabio Calefato, Filippo Lanubile. **The Challenges of Sentiment Detection in the Social Programmer Ecosystem**. In Proceedings of SSE '15, The 7th International Workshop on Social Software Engineering. [[PDF]](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3463652/SSE_Q%26A_CameraReady.pdf) [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/nolli82/the-challenges-of-sentiment-detection-in-the-social-programmer-ecosystem).
- Guo Li, Haiyi Zhu, Tun Lu, Xianghua Ding, Ning Gu. 
  **Is It Good to Be Like Wikipedia?: Exploring the Trade-offs of Introducing Collaborative Editing Model to Q&A Sites** (CSCW 2015). [[PDF]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2675155)
- Joshua Sunshine, James D. Herbsleb, and Jonathan Aldrich.
  **Searching the State Space: A Qualitative Study of API Protocol Usability** In Proceedings of the International Conference on Program Comprehension (ICPC 2015). [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jssunshi/pubs/icpc15-searching.pdf)
- Fabio Calefato, Filippo Lanubile, Maria Concetta Marasciulo, Nicole Novielli. **Mining Successful Answers in Stack Overflow**. In Proceedings of MSR 2015, The 12th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. [[PDF]](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3463652/PID3635881.pdf) [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/nolli82/msr2015-48218870).
- Christoffer Rosen, Emad Shihab, 2015. **What are mobile developers asking about? A large scale study using stack overflow**. In *Empirical Software Engineering, April 2015*. Springer Science+Business Media. [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10664-015-9379-3) [[PDF]](http://rd.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10664-015-9379-3.pdf)
- Arwan Achmad, Rochimah Siti, Akbar Rizky, January 2015. **Source code retrieval on StackOverflow using LDA**. In: *Information and Communication Technology (ICoICT), 2015 3rd International Conference on. IEEE, 2015*. p. 295-299. [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICoICT.2015.7231439)
- Chua, Alton YK, and Snehasish Banerjee. **Answers or no answers: Studying question answerability in Stack Overflow.** Journal of Information Science 41.5 (2015): 720-731.[[website]](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0165551515590096)
- Yun Zhang, David Lo, Xin Xia, Jian-Ling Sun. **Multi-Factor Duplicate Question Detection in Stack Overflow.** Journal of Computer Science and Technology (Volume 30, Issue 5, Pages 981–997) 2015. [[PDF]](https://soarsmu.github.io/papers/jcst-duplicateqns.pdf)
- Morakot Choetkiertikul, Daniel Avery, et al.
  **Who Will Answer My Question on Stack Overflow?**
  24th Australasian Software Engineering Conference 2015.
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7365804)

#### 2014

- Lei Xu, Tingting Nian, Luís Cabral. **What Makes Geeks Tick? A Study of Stack Overflow Careers** [[PDF]](http://leixu.org/Xu_JMP_Stack_Overflow.pdf)
- Siddharth Subramanian, Laura Inozemtseva, and Reid Holmes. 2014.
  **Live API Documentation**
  In *36th International Conference on Software Engineering*. ACM, pages 643-652
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2568225.2568313)
  [[PDF]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~rtholmes/papers/icse_2014_subramanian.pdf)
- Samuel Maurus and Claudia Plant, 2014. **Ternary Matrix Factorization**. In *IEEE International Conference on Data Mining, 2014 (ICDM 2014)*.
- Luca Ponzanelli, Andrea Mocci, Alberto Bacchelli, Michele Lanza. 2014. 
  **Improving Low Quality Stack Overflow Post Detection**. 
  In *30th International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution (ICSME'14)*. IEEE
  [[BibTeX]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/publications/ponz2014e/downloads/Ponz2014e-bib.bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/publications/ponz2014e/downloads/Ponz2014e.pdf)
  [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/lucaponzanelli/icsme-2014-industry)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Gabriele Bavota, Massimiliano Di Penta, Rocco Oliveto, Michele Lanza. 2014. 
  **Prompter: A Self-confident Recommender System**. 
  In *30th International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution (ICSME'14)*. 
  IEEE
  [[BibTeX]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/profile/publications/ponz2014d/Ponz2014d-bib.bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/lanza/Downloads/Ponz2014d.pdf)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Gabriele Bavota, Massimiliano Di Penta, Rocco Oliveto, Michele Lanza. 2014. 
  **Mining StackOverflow to Turn the IDE into a Self-confident Programming Prompter**. 
  In *11th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR'14)*. 
  ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2597073.2597077)
  [[BibTeX]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/publications/ponz2014b/downloads/Ponz2014b-bib.bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/ponzanelli/publications/ponz2014b/downloads/Ponz2014b.pdf)
- N. Novielli, F. Calefato, and F. Lanubile. 2014. 
  **Towards Discovering the Role of Emotions in Stack Overflow** In Proc. of the *6th International Workshop on Social Software Engineering* (colocated with FSE 2014) Hong Kong, nov. 2014 ACM [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2661685.2661689) [[PDF]](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3463652/SSE_Q%26A_CameraReady.pdf) [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/nolli82/towards-discovering-the-role-of-emotions-in-stack-overflow)
- G. Gkotsis, K. Stepanyan, C. Pedrinaci, J. Domingue, and M. Liakata. 2014.
  **It’s all in the content: State of the art best answer prediction based on discretisation of shallow linguistic features**. 
  In *2014 ACM Conference on Web Science (WebSci ’14)*. 
  ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2615569.2615681)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/GeorgeGkotsis/its-all-in-the-content-state-of-the-art-best-answer-prediction-based-on-discretisation-of-shallow-linguistic-features)
- Jose San Pedro, Alexandros Karatzoglou, 2014. 
  **Question recommendation for collaborative question answering systems with RankSLDA**. 
  In *8th Conference on Recommender systems (RecSys '14)*. 
  ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2645710.2645736)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.ci.tuwien.ac.at/~alexis/Publications_files/ltrlda-recsys14.pdf)
- Shaowei Wang, David Lo, Bogdan Vasilescu, and Alexander Serebrenik, 2014.
  **EnTagRec: An Enhanced Tag Recommendation System for Software Information Sites**.
  In *30th International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution (ICSME 2014)*.
  IEEE
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2597008.2597146)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bvasiles/papers/icsm14.pdf)
- Lucas Souza, Eduardo Campos, and Marcelo Maia. 2014.
  **Ranking Crowd Knowledge to Assist Software Development**.
  In *22nd International Conference on Program Comprehension (ICPC 2014)*.
  ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2597008.2597146)
  [[BibTeX]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2014/icpc2014.bib)
  [[PDF]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2014/ICPC2014preprint.pdf)
- Lucas Souza, Eduardo Campos, and Marcelo Maia. 
  **On the Extraction of Cookbooks for APIs from the Crowd Knowledge**. In *Proc. of the 28th Brazilian Symposium on Software Engineering - SBES'2014*. SBC-IEEE
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SBES.2014.15)
  [[BibTeX]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2014/sbesLucas2014.bib)
  [[PDF]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2014/SBES2014Lucas.pdf)
- Eduardo Campos, and Marcelo Maia. 
  **Automatic categorization of questions from Q&A sites**. In *ACM Symposium on Applied Computing - SAC'2014*. ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2554850.2555117)
  [[BibTeX]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2014/sac2014.bib)
  [[PDF]](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br/cms/userfiles/downloads/2014/SAC2014CameraReady.pdf)
- Kartik Bajaj, Karthik Pattabiraman, and Ali Mesbah. 2014.
  **Mining Questions Asked by Web Developers**.
  In *11th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2014)*.
  ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2597073.2597083)
  [[BibTeX]](http://salt.ece.ubc.ca/publications/kartik_msr14.html)
  [[PDF]](http://salt.ece.ubc.ca/publications/docs/kartik-msr14.pdf)
- Bogdan Vasilescu, Alexander Serebrenik, Prem Devanbu and Vladimir Filkov. 2014.
  **How social Q&A sites are changing knowledge sharing in open source software communities**
  In *17th ACM Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work and Social Computing (CSCW 2014)*.
  ACM
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2531602.2531659)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bvasiles/papers/cscw14.pdf)
- Alexander Halavais, K Hazel Kwon, Shannon Havener and Jason Striker. 2014.
  **Badges of Friendship: Social Influence and Badge Acquisition on Stack Overflow**.
  In *47th Hawaii International International Conference on Systems Science (HICSS-47 2014)*.
  IEEE
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/HICSS.2014.206)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://altcred.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/halavais-2014-badges-of-friendship.pdf)
- Megan Squire and Christian Funkhouser. 2014. 
  **"A Bit of Code": How the Stack Overflow Community Creates Quality Postings**
  In *47th Hawaii International International Conference on Systems Science (HICSS-47 2014)*.
  IEEE
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/HICSS.2014.185)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://flosshub.org/sites/flosshub.org/files/hicssSMFinalWatermark.pdf)
- Yla Tausczik, Aniket Kittur and Robert Kraut. 2014.
  **Collaborative problem solving: A study of Math Overflow**
  In *17th ACM Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work and Social Computing (CSCW 2014)*
  ACM, pages 355-367.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2531602.2531690)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ylataus/files/TausczikKitturKraut2014.pdf)
- Sangeeta Lal, Denzil Correa, and Ashish Sureka. 2014.
  **MiQs: Characterization and Prediction of Migrated Questions on StackExchange**.
  In *21st Asia-Pacific Software Engineering Conference (APSEC 2014)*
  [[PDF]](http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~ashish/APSEC2014SD.pdf)
- Denzil Correa and Ashish Sureka. 2014.
  **Chaff from the Wheat: Characterization and Modeling of Deleted Questions on Stack Overflow**
  In *Proceedings of the 23rd international conference on World wide web* (WWW '14). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 631-642. [[DOI]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2566486.2568036) [[PDF]](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19882021/pdf/fp789-correa.pdf)
- Baoguo Yang, Suresh Manandhar.
  **Tag-based expert recommendation in community question answering.**
  2014 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining (ASONAM 2014).
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6921702)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1483/discussion-on-answer-by-bogdan-vasilescu-academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-da).

Answer (score 23):

#### 2013

- Dana Movshovitz-Attias and William Cohen, 2013.
  **Natural Language Models for Predicting Programming Comments**
  In *Proceedings of the Association for Computational Linguistics*
  ACL
  [[BibTeX]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dmovshov/papers/bibs/dma_acl2013.txt)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dmovshov/papers/dma_acl2013.pdf)
- Shuo Chang and Aditya Pal, 2013.
  **Routing questions for collaborative answering in community question answering**
  In *Proceedings of the 2013 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining*
  ACM, pages 494-501
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2492517.2492559)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~schang/papers/13ASONAM.pdf)
- Priyanka Singh, Nigel Shadbolt, 2013.
  **Linked data in crowdsourcing purposive social network.** 
  In *WWW (Companion Volume)* 
  International World Wide Web Conferences Steering Committee, pages 913-918
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/www/SinghS13)
  [[PDF]](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2490000/2488079/p913-singh.pdf?ip=131.155.212.177&id=2488079&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=C2716FEBFA981EF12214637723A2BFB946E5CCD26CF057B5&CFID=407675569&CFTOKEN=36041845&__acm__=1391956563_704449f1a42baff0fa0c9249236cf45a)
- Edmund Wong, Jinqiu Yang, Lin Tan, 2013.
  **AutoComment: Mining question and answer sites for automatic comment generation.**
  In *ASE 2013*
  IEEE, pages 562-567
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ASE.2013.6693113)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/kbse/WongYT13)
  [[PDF]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6693113)
- Alexandru Lucian Ginsca, Adrian Popescu, 2013.
  **User profiling for answer quality assessment in Q&A communities**
  In *Proceedings of the 2013 workshop on Data-driven user behavioral modelling and mining from social media*
  ACM, pages 25-28.
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/cikm/GinscaP13)
  [[PDF]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2513579)
- Anders Søgaard, Hector Martinez, Jakob Elming, Anders Johannsen, 2013.
  **Using crowdsourcing to get representations based on regular expressions**
  In *2013 Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing*.
  ACL, pages 1476-1480
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/emnlp/SogaardMEJ13)
  [[PDF]](http://www.newdesign.aclweb.org/anthology/D/D13/D13-1154.pdf)
- Rahul Venkataramani, Atul Gupta, Allahbaksh M. Asadullah, Basavaraju Muddu, Vasudev D. Bhat, 2013.
  **Discovery of technical expertise from open source code repositories**
  In *Proceedings of the 22nd international conference on World Wide Web companion*
  International World Wide Web Conferences Steering Committee, pages 97-98
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/www/VenkataramaniGAMB13)
  [[PDF]](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2490000/2487832/p97-venkataramani.pdf?ip=131.155.212.177&id=2487832&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=C2716FEBFA981EF12214637723A2BFB946E5CCD26CF057B5&CFID=407675569&CFTOKEN=36041845&__acm__=1391953990_2d74628686898e88ff7703d5ea226fc1)
- Joshua Saxe, David Mentis, Chris Greamo, 2013.
  **Mining Web Technical Discussions to Identify Malware Capabilities**
  In *IEEE 33rd International Conference on Distributed Computing Systems Workshops*.
  IEEE, pages 1-5
  [[DOI]](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/ICDCSW.2013.56)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/icdcsw/SaxeMG13)
  [[PDF]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6679853)
- Amiangshu Bosu, Christopher S. Corley, Dustin Heaton, Debarshi Chatterji, Jeffrey C. Carver, Nicholas A. Kraft, 2013.
  **Building reputation in StackOverflow: an empirical investigation**
  In *Proceedings of the 10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories*.
  IEEE, pages 89-92.
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/msr/BosuCHCCK13)
  [[PDF]](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2490000/2487107/p89-bosu.pdf?ip=131.155.212.177&id=2487107&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=C2716FEBFA981EF12214637723A2BFB946E5CCD26CF057B5&CFID=407675569&CFTOKEN=36041845&__acm__=1391953213_15432ed61de1d2563a7c55d495b92287)
- David Kavaler, Daryl Posnett, Clint Gibler, Hao Chen, Premkumar Devanbu, Vladimir Filkov, 2013.
  **Using and Asking: APIs Used in the Android Market and Asked about in StackOverflow**
  In *Social Informatics*.
  Springer Verlag, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 8238, 2013, pp 405-418
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-03260-3_35)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/socinfo/KavalerPGCDF13)
  [[PDF]](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/468/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-319-03260-3_35.pdf?auth66=1392125565_5ff2f799830f69ca3f26e7605e15fe52&ext=.pdf)
- Mohammad Masudur Rahman, Shamima Yeasmin, Chanchal K. Roy, 2013
  **An IDE-Based Context-Aware Meta Search Engine**
  In *20th Working Conference on Reverse Engineering*.
  IEEE, pages 467-471.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/WCRE.2013.6671324)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/wcre/RahmanYR13)
  [[PDF]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6671324)
- Galina E. Lezina, Artem M. Kuznetsov, 2013.
  **Predict Closed Questions on StackOverﬂow**
  In *Proceedings of the Ninth Spring Researcher’s Colloquium on Database and Information Systems*
  CEUR-WS, Volume 1031, pages 10-14.
  [[PDF]](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1031/paper2.pdf)
- Dana Movshovitz-Attias, Yair Movshovitz-Attias, Peter Steenkiste and Christos Faloutsos, 2013.
  **Analysis of the reputation system and user contributions on a question answering website: StackOverflow** 
  In *Proceedings of the 2013 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining*
  ACM, pages 886-893 
  [[BibTeX]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dmovshov/papers/bibs/dma_asonam2013.txt)
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2492517.2500242)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dmovshov/papers/asonam_2013.pdf)
- Blerina Bazelli, Abram Hindle, Eleni Stroulia, 2013.
  **On the Personality Traits of StackOverﬂow Users**
  In *2013 IEEE International Conference on Software Maintenance*.
  IEEE, pages 460-463
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/icsm/BazelliHS13)
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICSM.2013.72)
  [[PDF]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6676932)
- Clayton Stanley, Michael D. Byrne. 2013.
  **Predicting Tags for StackOverﬂow Posts**
  In *12th International Conference on Cognitive Modelling*.
  , pages 414-419.
  [[PDF]](http://chil.rice.edu/research/pdf/StanleyByrne2013StackOverflow.pdf)
- Shaowei Wang, David Lo and Lingxiao Jiang. 2013.
  **An Empirical Study on Developer Interactions in StackOverflow**.
  In *28th Annual ACM Symposium on Applied Computing*.
  ACM, pages 1019-1024.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2480362.2480557)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.mysmu.edu/faculty/lxjiang/papers/sac13stackoverflow.pdf)
- Dennis Schenk and Mircea Lungu. 2013.
  **Geo-Locating the Knowledge Transfer in Stack Overflow**.
  In *International Workshop on Social Software Engineering*.
  ACM, pages 21-24.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2501535.2501540)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Sche13a-GeolocatingStackOverflow.pdf)
- Bogdan Vasilescu, Andrea Capiluppi and Alexander Serebrenik. 2013.
  **Gender, representation and online participation: A quantitative study**
  Interacting with Computers. 
  Oxford University Press. 1-24
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/iwc/iwt047)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://iwc.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2013/09/27/iwc.iwt047.full.pdf?keytype=ref&ijkey=YDfDyV3aWDFWeDl)
  [[SlideShare]](http://www.slideshare.net/andreacapiluppi/gender-representation-and-online-participation-a-quantitative-study)
  [[Gender tool]](http://github.com/tue-mdse/genderComputer)
- Bogdan Vasilescu, Vladimir Filkov and Alexander Serebrenik. 2013.
  **StackOverflow and GitHub: Associations between software development and crowdsourced knowledge**
  In *2013 ASE/IEEE International Conference on Social Computing*.
  IEEE, pages 188-195.
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bvasiles/papers/socialcom13.pdf)
  [[Slides]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bvasiles/socialcom13)
- Bogdan Vasilescu, Alexander Serebrenik, Mark G.J. van den Brand. 2013. 
  **The Babel of software development: Linguistic diversity in Open Source**
  In *5th International Conference on Social Informatics*.
  Springer LNCS 8238, pages 391-404.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-03260-3_34)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bvasiles/papers/socinfo13.pdf)
- Yuan Yao, Hanghang Tong, Tao Xie, Leman Akoglu, Feng Xu and Jian Lu. 2013.
  **Want a Good Answer? Ask a Good Question First!**
  [[arXiv]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6876)
  [[non-technical overview]](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/522171/data-mining-reveals-the-secret-to-getting-good-answers/)
  [[BbTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
- Denzil Correa and Ashish Sureka. 2013.
  **Fit or Unfit: Analysis and Prediction of 'Closed Questions' on Stack Overflow.** 
  In *2013 ACM Conference on Online Social Networks*.
  ACM, pages 201-212. 
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2512938.2512954)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7291)
- Luca Ponzanelli, Alberto Bacchelli and Michele Lanza. 2013.
  **Seahawk: Stack Overflow in the IDE** 
  In *2013 International Conference on Software Engineering*.
  IEEE, pages 1295-1298.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICSE.2013.6606701)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/bacchelli/publications/icse2013td.pdf)
- Ashton Anderson, Dan Huttenlocher, Jon Kleinberg, and Jure Leskovec. 2013. 
  **Steering User Behavior With Badges** 
  In *22nd International World Wide Web Conference (WWW’13)*.
  ACM, pages 95-106.
  [[DOI]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2488388.2488398)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/www13-badges.pdf)
- Miltiadis Allamanis and Charles Sutton. 2013. 
  **Why, When and What: Analyzing Stack Overflow Questions by Topic, Type & Code** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 53-56.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624004)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/msrCh2013.pdf)
- Muhammad Asaduzzaman, Ahmed Mashiyat, Chanchal Roy and Kevin Schneider. 2013. 
  **Answering Questions About Unanswered Questions of Stack Overflow** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 97-100.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624015)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.usask.ca/~croy/papers/2013/Asaduzzaman_MSR2013_SOChallenge.pdf)
- Amiangshu Bosu, Christopher Corley, Dustin Heaton, Debarshi Chatterji, Jeffrey Carver and Nicholas Kraft. 2013. 
  **Building Reputation in StackOverflow: An Empirical Investigation** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 89-92.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624013)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://cscorley.students.cs.ua.edu/_static/pubs/msr13-id184-p-15930-preprint.pdf)
- Joshua Campbell, Chenlei Zhang, Zhen Xu, Abram Hindle and James Miller. 2013. 
  **Deficient Documentation Detection: A Methodology to Locate Deficient Project Documentation using Topic Analysis** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 57-60.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624005)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joshua2/documentation.pdf)
  [[SlideShare]](http://www.slideshare.net/rayzhangcl/presentation-21607981)
- Carlos Gomez, Brendan Cleary and Leif Singer. 2013. 
  **A Study of Innovation Diffusion Through Link Sharing on Stack Overflow** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 81-84.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624011)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://leif.me/papers/Gomez2013.pdf)
- Scott Grant and Buddy Betts. 2013. 
  **Encouraging User Behaviour With Achievements: An Empirical Study** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 65-68.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624007)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/~scott/papers/MSR2013.pdf)
- Mario Linares-Vásquez, Bogdan Dit and Denys Poshyvanyk. 2013.
  **An Exploratory Analysis of Mobile Development Issues Using Stack Overflow** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 93-96.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624014)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~bdit/publications/MSR13_ChallengeSO_preprint.pdf)
- Patrick Morrison and Emerson Murphy-Hill. 2013.
  **Is Programming Knowledge Related To Age? - An Exploration of Stack Overflow** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 69-72.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624008)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://people.engr.ncsu.edu/ermurph3/papers/msr13.pdf)
- Avigit K. Saha, Ripon K. Saha and Kevin A. Schneider. 2013.
  **A Discriminative Model Approach for Suggesting Tags Automatically for Stack Overflow Questions** In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 73-76.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624009)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](https://webspace.utexas.edu/rks848/www/papers/msr13-id175-p-16622-preprint.pdf)
  In *Proceedings of the 23rd international conference on World wide web* (WWW '14). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 631-642. [[DOI]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2566486.2568036) [[PDF]](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19882021/pdf/fp789-correa.pdf)
- Vibha Singhal Sinha, Senthil Mani and Monika Gupta. 2013. 
  **Exploring Activeness of Users in Q&A Forums** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 77-80.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624010)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
- Siddharth Subramanian and Reid Holmes. 2013.
  **Making Sense of Online Code Snippets**
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 85-88.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624012)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~rtholmes/papers/msr_2013_subramanian.pdf)
  [[SlideShare]](http://www.slideshare.net/siddhukrs/making-sense-of-online-code-snippets-without-animation-without-video-demo)
  [[Demo]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srE9yA04S50)
- Wei Wang and Michael Godfrey. 2013.
  **Detecting API Usage Obstacles: A Study of iOS and Android Developer Questions**
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories. Mining Challenge*.
  IEEE, pages 61-64.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2013.6624006)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~migod/papers/2013/msr13-challenge.pdf)
- Ursula Martin and Alison Pease. 2013. **What does mathoverflow tell us about the production of mathematics?**.  In SOHUMAN, 2nd International Workshop on Social Media for Crowdsourcing and Human Computation, at ACM Web Science 2013, May 1, 2013, Paris. [[PDF]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0904v1)
- Xin Xia, David Lo, Xinyu Wang and Bo Zhou. 
  **Tag recommendation in software information sites.** 
  In *10th Working Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR), 2013*.
  [[PDF]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6624040)

Answer (score 20):

#### 2012

- Yla Tausczik and James Pennebaker. 2012.
  **Participation in an online mathematics community: Differentiating motivations to add**
  In *Proceedings of the ACM 2012 Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work*.
  ACM, pages 207-216.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2145204.2145237)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ylataus/files/TausczikPennebaker2012.pdf)
- Annie T. T. Ying. 2012.
  **Facilitating Code Example Search on the Web through Expertise Personalization**
  In *User Modeling, Adaptation, and Personalization*
  Springer Verlag, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 7379, pp 391-394
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-31454-4_43)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/um/Ying12)
  [[PDF]](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/889/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-642-31454-4_43.pdf?auth66=1392124472_b00ce47ade8221b7d19fe5c7f4ace7d7&ext=.pdf)
- Leman Akoglu, Duen Horng Chau, U. Kang, Danai Koutra and Christos Faloutsos. 2012. 
  **OPAvion: mining and visualization in large graphs**. 
  In *2012 ACM SIGMOD International Conference on Management of Data (SIGMOD'12)*. 
  ACM, pages 717-720.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2213836.2213941)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/sigmod/AkogluCKKF12)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lakoglu/pubs/sigmod12demo-opavion.pdf)
- Ashton Anderson, Daniel Huttenlocher, Jon Kleinberg and Jure Leskovec. 2012. 
  **Discovering value from community activity on focused question answering sites: a case study of Stack Overflow**. 
  In *ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining*
  [[DOI]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2339530.2339665)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/kdd/AndersonHKL12) 
  [[PDF]](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/sof-kdd12.pdf)
- Alberto Bacchelli, Luca Ponzanelli and Michele Lanza. 2012. 
  **Harnessing Stack Overflow for the IDE**. 
  In *2012 Third International Workshop on Recommendation Systems for Software Engineering (RSSE)*.
  IEEE, pages 26-30.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/RSSE.2012.6233404)
  [[BibTeX]](http://scholar.google.nl/scholar.bib?q=info:TC_b_AuILrQJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=nl&as_sdt=0,5&ct=citation&cd=0)
  [[PDF]](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/lanza/Downloads/Bacc2012b.pdf)
- Anton Barua, Stephen W. Thomas and Ahmed E. Hassan. 2012. **What are developers talking about? An analysis of topics and trends in Stack Overflow**. In *Empirical Software Engineering*
  [[BibTeX]](http://sailhome.cs.queensu.ca/replication/stackoverflow/)
  [[PDF]](http://sail.cs.queensu.ca/publications/pubs/Barua-2012-EMSE.pdf)
- Benjamin V. Hanrahan, Gregorio Convertino, and Les Nelson. 2012. **Modeling problem difficulty and expertise in stackoverflow**. In *ACM 2012 Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work Companion* (CSCW '12). ACM, pages 91-94. 
  [[DOI]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2141512.2141550)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/cscw/HanrahanCN12)
- Hewijin Jiau, and Feng-Pu Yang. 2012. **Facing up to the inequality of crowdsourced API documentation**. In *ACM SIGSOFT Software Engineering Notes*. 37 (1): 1-9.
  [[DOI]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2088883.2088892)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/sigsoft/JiauY12)
- Rafael Lotufo, Leonardo Passos and Krzysztof Czarnecki. 2012. **Towards improving bug tracking systems with game mechanisms**. In *Mining Software Repositories* 
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MSR.2012.6224293)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/msr/LotufoPC12)
  [[PDF]](http://gsd.uwaterloo.ca/bts-game-mechanisms)
- Seyed Mehdi Nasehi, Jonathan Sillito, Frank Maurer and Chris Burns. 2012. **What Makes a Good Code Example? A Study of Programming Q&A in StackOverflow**.  In *IEEE International Conference on Software Maintenance (ICSM 2012)*. IEEE.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/ICSM.2012.6405249)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/icsm/NasehiSMB12)
  [[PDF]](http://ase.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/uploads/Publications/WhatMakeAGoodExample-ICSM2012.pdf)
- Aditya Pal, F. Maxwell Harper and Joseph A. Konstan. 2012. **Exploring Question Selection Bias to Identify Experts and Potential Experts in Community Question Answering**. In *ACM Trans. Inf. Syst., vol.30, no.2, pages 10*.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2180868.2180872)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/tois/PalHK12)
  [[PDF]](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~apal/res/tois12_expertidentification.pdf)
- Aditya Pal, Shuo Chang, and Joseph A. Konstan. 2012. **Evolution of Experts in Question Answering Communities**. In *6th International AAAI Conference on Weblogs and Social Media*.
  [[DOI]](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/ICWSM12/paper/view/4653)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/icwsm/PalCK12)
  [[PDF]](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~apal/res/icwsm12_expertevolution.pdf)
- Chris Parnin, Christoph Treude, Lars Grammel, and Margaret-Anne Storey. 2012. **Crowd documentation: Exploring the coverage and the dynamics of API discussions on Stack Overflow**. Georgia Tech Technical Report GIT-CS-12-05.
  [[PDF]](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vector/papers/CrowdDoc-GIT-CS-12-05.pdf)
- Daryl Posnett, Eric Warburg, Premkumar Devanbu and Vladimir Filkov. 2012. **Mining Stack Exchange: Expertise is Evident From Initial Contributions**. In *2012 ASE International Conference on Social Informatics*.
- Fatemeh Riahi. 2012. **Finding expert users in community question answering services using topic models**, Master's Thesis, Dalhousie University, Halifax, Nova Scotia.
  [[PDF]](http://dalspace.library.dal.ca/bitstream/handle/10222/14580/Riahi%2c%20Fatemeh%2c%20MSc%2c%20CS%2c%20February%202012.pdf)
- Leif Singer, Fernando Figueira Filho, Brendan Cleary, Christoph Treude, Margaret-Anne Storey, and Kurt Schneider. 2012. **Mutual assessment in the social programmer ecosystem: an empirical investigation of developer profile aggregators**. Technical report, University of Hannover, Germany.
  [[PDF]](http://leif.me/papers/MutualAssessment-DCS-347-IR.pdf)
- Christoph Treude, Fernando Figueira Filho, Brendan Cleary, and Margaret-Anne Storey. 2012. **Programming in a socially networked world: the evolution of the social programmer**. In *Future of Collaborative Software Development Workshop*.
  [[PDF]](http://ctreude.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/programming_in_a_socially_networked_world.pdf)
- Bogdan Vasilescu, Andrea Capiluppi and Alexander Serebrenik. 2012. 
  **Gender, representation and online participation: A quantitative study of StackOverflow**. 
  In *2012 ASE/IEEE International Conference on Social Informatics*.
  IEEE, pages 332-338.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SocialInformatics.2012.81)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~bvasiles/papers/socinfo12.pdf)
- Jakob Voß. 2012. 
  **Linking Folksonomies to Knowledge Organization Systems**. 
  In *6th Conference on Metadata and Semantics Research* (MTSR '12). 
  Springer, pages 89-97. 
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-35233-1_9) 
  [[HTML]](http://jakobib.github.com/mtsr2012/paper.html) 
  [[PDF]](http://jakobib.github.com/mtsr2012/paper.pdf) 
  [[Slides](http://de.slideshare.net/nichtich/linking-folksonomies-to-knowledge-organization-systems)]
- Alexey Zagalsky, Ohad Barzilay, and Amiram Yehudai. 2012. 
  **Example overflow: Using social media for code recommendation**. 
  In *Third International Workshop on Recommendation Systems for Software Engineering (RSSE 2012)*.
  IEEE, pages 38-42.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/RSSE.2012.6233407)
  [[PDF]](http://alexeyza.com/pdf/rsse12.pdf)

Answer (score 17):

#### 2011

- Yla Tausczik and James Pennebaker. 2011.
  **Predicting the Perceived Quality of Online Mathematics Contributions from Users' Reputations**
  In *Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems*.
  ACM, pages 1885--1888.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1978942.1979215)
  [[BibTeX]](https://gist.github.com/bvasiles/4987059#file-stackoverflow-bib)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eylataus/files/TausczikPennebaker2011.pdf)
- Zainab Zolaktaf, Fatemeh Riahi, Mahdi Shafiei, Evangelos Milios, 2011.
  **Modeling Community Question Answering archives**.
  In *Workshop on Computational Social Science and the Wisdom of Crowds, Neural Information Processing Systems*, December 17, 2011, Sierra Nevada, Spain.
  [[BibTeX]](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Eeem/cvWeb/bib/2011-Zolaktaf-NIPS.bib)
  [[PDF]](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Eeem/cvWeb/pubs/2011-Zolaktaf-NIPS.pdf)
- Lena Mamykina, Bella Manoim, Manas Mittal, George Hripcsak, and Björn Hartmann. 2011. **Design lessons from the fastest q&a site in the west**. In *2011 Annual Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems* (CHI '11). ACM, pages 2857-2866.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1978942.1979366)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/chi/MamykinaMMHH11)
  [[PDF]](http://bid.berkeley.edu/files/papers/mamykina-stackoverflow-chi2011.pdf)
- Toby Osbourn. 2011. **Getting the most out of the web**. *IEEE Software*, vol.28, no.1, pages 96.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/MS.2011.6)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/software/Osbourn11)
- Aditya Pal, Rosta Farzan, Joseph A. Konstan and Robert E. Kraut. 2011. **Early detection of potential experts in question answering communities**. In *19th International Conference on User Modeling, Adaption and Personalization* (UMAP'11). Springer, pages 231-242.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-22362-4_20)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/um/PalFKK11)
  [[PDF]](http://kraut.hciresearch.org/sites/kraut.hciresearch.org/files/open/pal11-EarlyDedtectionOfPotentialExperts.pdf)
- Chris Parnin, and Christoph Treude. **Measuring API documentation on the web**. 2011. In *2nd International Workshop on Web 2.0 for Software Engineering* (Web2SE’11), ACM, pages 25–30.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1984701.1984706)
  [[BibTeX]](http://researchr.org/publication/ParninTreude2011/bibtex)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/%7Evector/papers/webdocumentation.pdf)
- Nidhi Raj, Lipika Dey, and Bhakti Gaonkar. 2011. **Expertise prediction for social network platforms to encourage knowledge sharing**. In *2011 IEEE/WIC/ACM International Conferences on Web Intelligence and Intelligent Agent Technology*, Vol. 1. IEEE, pages 380-383.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/WI-IAT.2011.93)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/webi/RajDG11)
- Daniel Schall and Florian Skopik: **An analysis of the structure and dynamics of large-scale Q/A communities**. ADBIS'11 15th International Conference on Advances in Databases and Information Systems.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-23737-9_21)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/adbis/SchallS11)
  [[PDF]](http://www.danielschall.at/2011_adbis_schall_skopik.pdf)
- Christoph Treude, Ohad Barzilay, and Margaret-Anne D. Storey. 2011. **How do programmers ask and answer questions on the web?: NIER track**. In *33rd International Conference on Software Engineering* (ICSE'11), IEEE, pages 804-807.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1985793.1985907)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/icse/TreudeBS11)
  [[PDF]](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/research/ohad.barzilay/publications/how-do-programmers-ask-and-answer-questions-on-the-web.pdf)
- Zainab Zolaktaf, Fatemeh Riahi, Mahdi Shaﬁei, and Evangelos Milios. **Modeling community question-answering archives**. Technical report, Faculty of Computer Science, Dalhousie University, Canada.
  [[PDF]](http://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Eeem/cvWeb/pubs/2011-Zolaktaf-NIPS.pdf)

#### 2010

- Barthélémy Dagenais and Martin P. Robillard. 2010, **Creating and evolving developer documentation: understanding the decisions of open source contributors** In *18th ACM SIGSOFT International Symposium on Foundations of Software Engineering* (FSE '10), ACM, pages 127-136.
  [[DOI]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1882291.1882312)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/sigsoft/DagenaisR10)
  [[PDF]](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1890000/1882312/p127-dagenais.pdf?ip=130.15.219.132&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&CFID=145616248&CFTOKEN=39765577&__acm__=1345768338_481f53f7c1a89f55e25de627fb9eb134)
- Ravi Kumar, Yury Lifshits, and Andrew Tomkins. 2010. **Evolution of two-sided markets**. In *3rd ACM International Conference on Web Search and Data Mining* (WSDM '10). ACM, pages 311-320.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1718487.1718526)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/wsdm/KumarLT10)
  [[PDF]](http://www.tomkinshome.com/site_media/papers/papers/KLT10.pdf)
  [[Slides]](http://www.slideshare.net/yurylifshits/evolution-of-two-sided-markets-yury-lifshits-wsdm-2010)
- Hüseyin Oktay, Brian J. Taylor, and David D. Jensen. 2010. **Causal discovery in social media using quasi-experimental designs**. In *First Workshop on Social Media Analytics* (SOMA '10). ACM, pages 1-9.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1964858.1964859)
  [[BibTeX]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1964858.1964859)
  [[PDF]](http://aileron.cs.umass.edu/papers/oktay-et-al-soma2010.pdf)
- Matthew J.H. Rattigan and David Jensen. 2010. **Leveraging D-Separation for Relational Data Sets**. In *2010 IEEE International Conference on Data Mining (ICDM '10)*. IEEE, pages 989-994.
  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICDM.2010.142)
  [[BibTeX]](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/icdm/RattiganJ10)
  [[PDF]](https://web.cs.umass.edu/publication/docs/2010/UM-CS-2010-071.pdf)

#### 2009

- Erik Wilde
  **Feeds as Query Result Serializations**
  In *arXiv:0911.2193 [cs.NI]*
  [[arXiv]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2193v1.pdf)

Comment: Daniel Schall and Florian Skopik: **An analysis of the structure and dynamics of large-scale Q/A communities.** ADBIS'11 15th International Conference on Advances in Databases and Information Systems.             This paper is not about Stack Exchange