# Has there ever been a breakthrough on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, research, publicity, academic

Has there ever been a breakthrough that happened on one of the Stack Exchange sites?  For example:

> Q: Does P = NP?
>   A: Yes, because [indisputable proof goes here].

Perhaps a question with a community wiki where a few smart people collaborated and output something brilliant.

Comment: *blushes* well all my posts... :P

Comment: "Has there been a breakthrough on Wikipedia?" Just by asking yourself this question you can see how it feels. While SE is better than Wikipedia, it is not a paradise for research-minded folks.

Comment: +1 This could make for an awesome series of blog posts telling the story of times SE made a big difference. Not just maths / science, I also remember seeing some high-drama "people helped to overcome injustice" type posts on Travel and Workplace

Comment: Related (possible duplicate) from 2019: [Academic Advancements Made on the Stack Exchange Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330335/335251)

Comment: Also somewhat related (but it includes research *about* SO/SE as well): [Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/335251)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None as big as P=NP, but there has been original research on some Stack Exchange sites — threads leading to a solution of an open problem.

Mathematics: [Best of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow)

Theoretical computer science: [Original proofs generated on the parent site](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/784/original-proofs-generated-on-the-parent-site)