# Academic Advancements Made on the Stack Exchange Network

Tags: discussion, research, academic

Have any significant/notable academic advancements (like new theorems or proofs in mathematics, or new scientific concepts, etc.) emerged from discussions on the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate) from 2019: [Has there ever been a breakthrough on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259803/335251)

Comment: Also somewhat related (but it includes research *about* SO/SE as well): [Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/335251)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), the question and answer site for professional mathematicians in the Stack Exchange network, has a topic on their Meta about this:
[Best of MathOverflow, or papers inspired by MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/70594)

> This is a place to collect MathOverflow success stories!
>
> Was some of your research inspired by something on MathOverflow? Do you know questions & answers that led to interesting research? MathOverflow citations? Open problems solved on MathOverflow?

Theoretical Computer Science has the link @HDE226868 found, [References to cstheory in the literature](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1257/32711), but also a list of [original proofs generated on the site](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/784/32711).

Answer (score 7):

As [Glorfindel said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330339/274942), [Math Overflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/74879) has led to a number of published papers, but it's not the only site in which this has happened. [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2970/170257) has inspired or directly lead to several papers over the years. Other sites have had posts cited by academic papers (e.g. [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1257)), and I would be very surprised if there aren't many instances of this across the network.

Also see answers to [Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/303080).