# Where one can ask survey kind of questions about Stack Exchange/ Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I have few questions regarding the behaviour of users on Stack Exchange which I want to know about from the users of Stack Exchange. Is there any proper platform to ask such questions where I can get sufficient response?
Can meta sites serve this purpose?

Comment: Nope. No such place.

Comment: That said, you might find some of the links on this question's answers interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data

Answer (score 1):

Meta is just like any other site a Q/A site, not a site for polls or surveys. Your survey is simply off-topic here.

There is no other place on the network where you can ask such questions, well, you could ask in a chat room where you are a regular user.

If possible you could post the theory you have in a question format so others can formula an answer, maybe they even have statistics to support their answer. If that is possible depends all on your question.