# Contacting someone from Stack Overflow team?

Tags: support, contact

Is it possible to contact someone from the Stack Overflow team?

I would like to send a very interesting paper to the product manager or someone who receives those things to forward them to the responsible team member.

Comment: There's a "contact us" link in the footer...

Comment: See that "contact us" link in the footer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact - that's the best way to reach us.

Comment: I've used the contact us page on stackoverflow, but does not get a response. I try it again.

Comment: @Oded is it possible that I send you the mail I already send to someone else?

Comment: Allow [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100) for a response ...

Comment: May also be relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data

Comment: @Shog9 this is a completly different kind of paper.

Comment: I am very much unlikely to be the right person for whatever it is you need.

Comment: Oded but could you forward the mail to the right person? Sorry for annoying you, otherwise I'll try the "official" way again :)

Comment: @BendEg You haven't been very forthcoming about what it is that you're trying to share, but I would consider the possibility that it was received the first time, and no one was interested in pursuing it.  I'm sure the SO team receives a great many submissions, and if it isn't something that really piques their interest, then maybe that's it.

Comment: @Oded it is now about 12month ago and I did not get any answer from the official contact address. I've send the paper to you too, had you time to take a look at it / redirect it to someone who is "responsible" :) ? Thank you for any information!

Comment: 12 months? I think you mean a few weeks, @BendEg - as GentlePurpleRain has suggested, there is probably no interest in following up on it internally.

Comment: @Oded Ups yes, I mean 12 weeks, sorry. Ok, if you had take a quick look at it and it is not interresting than it's ok, just don't want that it may goes to the garbage directly :)

Comment: The idea of paying people for their contributions on Stack Overflow (and the rest of the network) is not new. And we have been against it for a long time. Perhaps this will shed some light on why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation

Comment: @Oded ok, then I've may be expressed myself wrong. Just ignore the paper, I've got some other interested parties. Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many of the [Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do) (aka Community Managers) have a direct email address in their profile.

This means they allow users to directly email them.

You can try emailing one of them and ask if they got your request. But please, don't mass email more than one, and don't send more than one email.

Comment: Sure, don't want to annoy anyone