# Is there a way to systematically find duplicate or similar posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-analysis

I am planning to do some analysis on duplicated or similar question posts from Stack Overflow. Therefore, I need to collect the posts (regardless of question or answer) as the ground truth data, which are duplicate or similar to each other.

Is there a systematic way to collect such data?

I found there is CloseReasonTypeId=101 which indicates the post is duplicate to another one. However, very few posts are flagged, leading to a very small data set. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Oh how I wish there were...

Comment: You could google the titles of every question and see what other SO question comes up and then manually check them.

Comment: Related: *[Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495)*. Includes (my emphasis): ***1)*** *"Yuji Mizobuchi, Kuniharu Takayama. Two improvements to **detect duplicates** in Stack Overflow. 24th IEEE International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER 2017)."* and ***2)*** *"M. Ahasanuzzaman, M. Asaduzzaman, Chanchal K. Roy, Kevin A. Schneider: Mining **duplicate questions** in Stack Overflow ?. 13th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories (MSR 2016)."*

Comment: If and when you publish the result in one form or the other, please make sure to spell Stack Overflow correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, here's an SEDE that'll pull posts closed as duplicate as well as the first dupe target:

```
SELECT TOP 10
  'https://stackoverflow.com/q/' + CAST(p.Id AS nvarchar) AS [Post],
  'https://stackoverflow.com/q/' + CAST(JSON_VALUE(ph.Text, '$.OriginalQuestionIds[0]') AS nvarchar) AS [Dupe]
FROM PostHistory ph
  JOIN Posts p ON p.Id = ph.PostId
WHERE 
  p.PostTypeId = 1 -- Question
  AND ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 10 -- Close event
  AND ph.Comment = 101 -- Dupe
```

[Here's the query in action](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1162439)