# Who do I contact if I am a researcher interested in researching StackExchange?

Tags: support, status-completed, research

I am a doctoral student in Educational Technology and am interested in writing my dissertation on StackExchange functionality. In particular, I want to evaluate content-creating functionality to determine the extent to which users can create content that reduces barriers to learning. I won't get too technical about that here.

This is applied research, and the dissertation would include a set of recommendations for improvement. I'm just curious who at StackExchange I can contact to alert them of this research in case they would like to see a copy of the final paper. Is there an email address users can send inquiries to?

Comment: You could add a link to your final paper [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) if you think it's relevant

Comment: Look for the research partnership post on meta SO. Though Julia Silge took care of those, she has resigned so I don't know if anyone else is currently taking care of this.

Comment: Please email me with details on your request, I will make sure that it gets to the right person.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I don't know your email address, but I emailed academic-research@stackoverflow.com, which is what is recommended on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377152/stack-overflow-academic-research-partnership-program). Is there anything else I should do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MitchellBoldin [check out this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377152/51) for more details (including google form for submitting more details)

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377152/51) gives details on the Stack Overflow Academic Research Partnership Program, and how to apply.