# Is it good or bad that a question has more or fewer answers?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Can we relate the quality of a question with the number of answers? There might be a number of non-useful answers, on the other hand, there might be fewer useful answers. Therefore, is it wise to correlate the question quality with the answer count only? If not, what other factors should we consider?

Comment: Should we really consider question quality at all? I think the most valuable part of these sites are the answers. They are in essence what transfers knowledge between people. A well written and researched question helps to attract good answers, but is not essential to that.

Comment: You might be interested in this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data It lists some scientific publications done with SE data, some include analysis on question quality.

Comment: Yeah, I regularly visit that post and have read almost all the papers. However, their general view is that good-quality questions have more answers. But really only the number matters!! @Luuklag

Comment: "*If not, what other factors should we consider?*" All other factors.

Comment: A great or poor question can have from zero to many answers, those answers can range in quality from wrong to profound - also, neither view count nor upvotes ensure a quality Q or A. Any *rule* or formula one could devise is not going to apply equally to all our sites. --- We already have the system of reading and (hopefully) voting correctly, and that the result ought to reflect the quality of the question or answer - and new answers or questions have fewer views and votes, though they are not necessarily worse than older questions or answers - so **how** would you propose we measure?

Answer (score 7):

Surely the most obvious and direct way to measure question quality is simply to look at its score.

You might want to look at its age too i.e. how quickly has it achieved that score because a question with a score of 10 in 1 year seems like it might be outdoing a similar question that's taken 10 years to achieve that same score.

Fundamentally though questions are there to solicit answers, whether a question has one or more answers is not really a problem. A single answer may always solve the question's problem or it might have several possible solutions covered by multiple answers. Neither case would seem to make the question better or worse in and of itself.

Of course there are probably exceptions for some sites. Let me give some examples.

- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) - generally questions are written such that the question poster knows the "right" answer already. So if a question attracts lots of different answers, maybe that's a sign that the puzzle doesn't have that one unique solution that the puzzle setter thought it had.
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com) - here a plethora of solutions are enouraged in different programming languages and just because you have a solution in 20 characters in Python, doesn't mean that a solution in 30 characters in Perl isn't just as welcome. Here more solutions probably do correlate with your question being more popular.

Comment: What about Stack Overflow? A programming problem can be resolved in multiple ways. Then, in SO, more answers mean the question is more popular.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true, although in some cases it might be. So as with most sites I don't think you can generalise with that one.

Comment: I disagree with the (positive) score being a measurement of quality, because this has a lot to do with a community's size, on how a question is written, how long the question is, &c.

Comment: @joachim A community's size may certainly have an effect on the absolute score so you might want to account for that if you were to compare different communities.