# Does Stack Exchange offer any incentives related to use of their data explorer in research?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump, research

I'm interested in whether or not there have historically been this sort of partnership with research in the academic space or if it is planned for the future. This could be something like a grant, scholarship, or just support from the developers.

I understand there could be a blog post about this information, but other than a great answer referencing [papers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) and some success stories from [Mathematics](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/70594), I do not see any formal effort. I would expect more interest to leverage the public data dumps, such as a conference or publication related to their use, but maybe this compromises some copyright thing I don't know about?

Comment: Related (2022-08-29): *[Stack Overflow is launching a Student Ambassador Program. Here’s how to apply](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/08/29/stack-overflow-student-ambassador-program-how-to-apply/)*

Comment: why would they? they already offer it for free, and it's useful. it's already apparently [difficult to get them to give back to open source communities](/q/383963/997587), which is already [part of their moderator agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement). and as a user of SEDE, I find it difficult to imagine why someone would want an extra incentive to do cool/interesting things with something that's freely available.

Comment: @starball Outsourcing data analysis. Being more visible in the research community. Etc.

Comment: Other open source communities such as HathiTrust provide support @starball https://www.hathitrust.org/, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, there was indeed [such a program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377152/stack-overflow-academic-research-partnership-program). However, it's not currently supported. It was more of a way to collaborate and did not really provide other incentives as far as I'm aware.

If you set alerts for Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow in Google Scholar, you'll soon be buried in related research. I'm not sure how up-to-date the [papers using Stack Exchange data answer is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data). I can see some papers missing off the top of my head, unless they were not added for lack of peer review.

Comment: Thank you. This form was what I was after - I will keep checking back to see if there are updates.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Stack Exchange offer any incentives related to use of their data explorer in research?

As far as I know, no. There is a fair amount of [papers using Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/178179) data, and I haven't seen any mentions of
Stack Exchange incentives in the few ones I went through (acknowledgement sections). On the contrary, Stack Exchange is looking at [monetizing the use of its data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/178179).

Comment: Should probably throw an update on this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396597/data-dumps-releases-timeline-updates-and-clarification?cb=1

Comment: Sorry wrong link - here is the one I meant to AUP https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396252/updates-to-the-acceptable-use-policy-aup-january-2024?cb=1 I meant to share, still valid answer framing the lack of commitment to promoting the site for research purposes formally.