# How do you measure your audience? What baselines are available?

Tags: discussion, analytics

Is there any attempt to measure who is using the Stack sites or how that audience has changed over time?

What does the audience look like today? What are you trying to make it look like in 6 months? In a year? In 2 years?

Comment: There are ways to measure traffic stats and stuff. It is a privilege that is awarded at 25k on graduated sites, and 5k on beta sites.

Comment: I imagine the audience of [cooking.se] being different from the audience of [gaming.se], which itself is different from the audience of [biology.se], and so on...

Comment: I'm looking for where the results are published and what they mean

Comment: Some of that info might be available from research done by universities but that might not be available to the public. You can do your own research in [sede](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Or look at other studies already done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71947/is-there-any-academic-research-going-on-regarding-stack-exchange

Answer (score 3):

All Stack Exchange sites have a site-analytics privilege. It is awarded at...

- 5k on beta sites
- 25k on graduated sites

This provides basic data, on the posts and traffic that a site may get.

There is also the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) which is available to everyone, and free to use. There are many queries that have already been written and are free to use.

This is data that you can collect and analyze yourself.

> What are you trying to make it look like in 6 months? In a year? In 2 years?

Well, some sites have goals, and others don't. The goal of Stack Exchange is not to become the smallest community on the internet within 10 years, but to create a compilation of knowledge that anyone interested can participate in and learn more about. This is how SE thrives now, and will continue to thrive in the future.

---

As rene noted, there are also institutions that make studies out of data that SE provides. You can learn more from [this blogpost](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data/).

Answer (score 2):

Some (necessarily approximate) demographic data is available from Quantcast: follow the link `quantcast.com/site_domain`, for example https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!demo

According to Quantcast:

- 90% of SO users are male
- 28% are of age 25-34.
- 52% of them have a college degree, and 27% have a higher-level (graduate) degree
- 57% of them have children

and so on...

---

The gender distribution is different, e.g., for Seasoned Advice: https://www.quantcast.com/cooking.stackexchange.com#!demo

Comment: The fact that 90% of SO's user base is male is a depressing statistic.