# How can I request a permanent ban of my own account on all sites?

Tags: support, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

Can I ask Stack Exchange moderators or employees to ban me permanently on two or three emails, all the emails I have, on every SE site? I mean forever, no coming back unless I start a new email account and then register it.

I am mentally ill, and am suffering from using this site. I often delete my account, but I just come back again.

I mean this warmly, but I have psychological problems and I feel that the ability to participate in the network is not good for them.

Comment: I'll try emailing if this is not attended to here

Comment: Moderators can only ban you for up to a year on their own site, so this would have to be handled by staff.

Comment: If you have such an issue that you require the site to permanently block all your currently known emails, there will be nothing to stop you creating another email and another profile and using these instead.

Comment: True, I suppose. But it would be more difficult to do @Nij as well as slightly obnoxious of me

Comment: Just curious: what is the end goal here? Because even being suspended/banned doesn't prevent you from deleting and creating a new account *using the same email*, even though the new account will be automatically suspended too.

Comment: Ask someone else to install [Net Nany](https://www.netnanny.com/features/website-blocker/), or other parental control software, on your device(s), and block SO/SE domains. Will be harder for you to bypass this.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, and I might do so again. Thanks for the headsup @ShadowTheKidWizard

Comment: Yes, it would be more difficult and it would be more obnoxious. That hasn't stopped people yet.

Comment: You could add some custom entries to /etc/hosts on your device so it won't take you to stack exchange at all.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32299/369802 has plenty of solutions that you can do all by yourself, without bothering others. Honestly if none of the things there work for you, you're also not going to be stopped by having your current e-mails banned, because the thought of just registering with a new e-mail is already there for you. You'll just end up bothering people to get that email banned too.
It's also faster than waiting for requests to be handled too.

Comment: Related: *["Ban myself" button in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32299/)*, *[How can I get help with Stack Overflow addiction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69560/)*, *[What aspects of psychology does Stack Overflow take advantage of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56797)*, *[How can I keep from getting addicted to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4004/)*, *[SO parallels to gambling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224670/)*, and *[How do I prevent a Stack Overflow addiction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91609/)*.

Comment: Would the [hosts file method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/ban-myself-button-in-user-profiles/32308#32308) work for you? ([Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).)

Comment: fair comment, thanks @Tinkeringbell but I am impulsive rather than addicted.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it's trivial to just edit it back when the urge to use SE arise again. The point is doing something that can't be undone.

Answer (score 14):

> I often delete my account, but I just come back again.

The problem with this is there is no way to identify you as a person and stop you from using this site. Even if your emails were banned (after making sure each and every one of them actually belong to you), you could just create a new one.

> I am mentally ill, and am suffering from using this site.

Please consider seeing a medical professional to help you with this. That's what doctors are there for. There is no practical way to keep you from using this site, it is up to *you* to make sure you either don't, or get help making it less problematic. That might be hard, but it is the only way that works in practice.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a personal request for the exceptional handling of an account.

These matters can be brought up by going to the [Contact Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), which can be found on all sites in the StackExchange network by going to the Help Center (through the button with the question mark in the top menu bar).

Answer (score 4):

Only staff can issue suspensions longer than 1 year, and only staff can issue network-wide suspensions.

You can contact staff via the [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).  Select "Other" under "What can we help you with?" and explain that you would like your accounts to be permanently suspended network-wide.  You may wish to include a brief explanation of the fact that you are trying to stop using the sites and would like assistance with that.

---

This advice has been checked with staff and confirmed to be accurate.