# Could SE actually work without voting?

Tags: discussion, voting

So content will simply be "bumped" with the most recent interaction or update, like the usual forums/threads, etc.

I have very rarely voted on anything in recent years (usually just looking for something specific and will move on regardless I find the answer or not), not that I see this as a bad thing, but rather I know what I want from the site and have gotten rather efficient at it.

Also, over time I have realized a +3 content may very well be rubbish, especially for obscure topics. Votes can be a reflection of popularity rather than actual knowledge, and when that happens it is not very different from ChatGPT.

Lastly, I believe actors are capable of good behavior at a fundamental level. Votes can be an inducement but it should not be seen as essential, to the point where people resort to repwhoring.

Comment: Then how would this be in any way better than "the usual forums or threads etc"? The site was very conspicuously designed to avoid several common problems with legacy forums.

Comment: @triplesee traditional forums will not be threatened by any moderation strike

Comment: Yeah, because nobody would bother moderating them, because they'd be full of junk rated equally to anything worth reading.

Comment: Would you have written 200 answers, if none of them had gotten more than 0/0 votes?

Comment: @Nij and who gets to define "junk"?

Comment: The community does. How do they show it? By voting.

Comment: @nvoigt as opposed to 200 replies on a random forum? maybe. If you checked my reputation history you can tell I have not been farming anything

Comment: @Nij what if the community is uninformed or dominated by uninformed users? why should any single user place their trust in such a community?

Comment: You mean like Quora and Reddit? Well, go take a look at their content. You see how it's different on Stack Exchange? That should tell you a lot about how informed an SE community is. If not, well, you may as well go there instead of trying to make SE be something it never could or should.

Comment: @Nij I don't see SE as being any different at its core. In the end it is about the content, the moderators derive their power from votes (not content), if the votes are actually not that powerful, the strike will not lead to anywhere. This is the point I am trying to make.

Comment: Cool, you don't see the point in Stack Exchange. Have fun, so long, bye now... What exactly are you expecting here, that everybody else should abandon a functional system because of an arbitrary what-if that does not match reality?

Comment: @Nij I am only here for the content (not votes or reputation). I don't rely on ChatGPT to determine the value/score of the post, it cannot help with obscure topics anyway.

Comment: And now you can go full circle on your own by reading from my first comment. Good luck figuring out anything if you can't see why "only here for the content" is not at all relevant as a point.

Comment: *"I don't rely on ChatGPT to determine the value/score of the post"* which, of course, is something it simply cannot do at all… amongst many things.

Comment: Iirc someone set up a SO alternative on discourse. Didn't keep track but if you felt it was a viable model... Give it a shot?

Comment: In what way do moderators derive power from votes? If anything it reduced the moderators power since it's a external rating system that mods have no control over. Mods can't even see who votes for what.

Comment: "Votes can be a reflection of popularity rather than actual knowledge" I completely disagree. Take a look at my profile (on SO), I've had a decent amount of upvotes, even made a suggestion that was received quite positively even though I'm pratically a nobody to this community. I've equally seen a lot of high rep users questions/answers get downvoted. Questions and answers are rated on quality. Having high rep gives you more credibility, but its your content that gets judged in the end of the day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What aspects of psychology does Stack Overflow take advantage of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56469/what-aspects-of-psychology-does-stack-overflow-take-advantage-of)

Comment: Content **is** "bumped" with most recent interaction or update - if you view by active, which is the default view.

Comment: This post requires a way lot more work. First, is this only about upvotes / downvotes of questions and answers? How would the SO/SE sites **tour** look if voting is removed? How would the reputation system work?

Answer (score 19):

No, the site can't work without some form of voting by "trusted" users. The entire point of Stack Exchange is to crowdsource credibility so that any correct answer gets visibility regardless of who wrote it or what credentials they have. Getting rid of that aspect entirely would be throwing the baby out with the bath water.

Does the current system need improvement? Absolutely, but throwing away the idea that users rate content isn't the right approach.

Comment: "*any correct answer gets visibility regardless of who wrote it or what credentials they have.*" That is an inaccurate premise because (1) the herd effect is very present in voting, and (2) mods' so-called "diamond" does not imply that their answers are accurate, let alone of high quality.

Answer (score 4):

One of the primary things (only primary thing?) votes are supposed to indicate is *usefulness* of content. Look at the vote button tooltips. That's one of the most core mechanics of the Stack Exchange model. Look at the [tour](/tour). How else would you propose to let good content rise to the top while retaining the property that actual people and not just some closed set of administrator-like users can influence that?

No. I don't think the Stack Exchange model could work without any kind of voting.

There could be changes to *kinds* of voting. Ex. If I understand correctly, Codidact has more fine grained vote types with specific meanings.